# IBOutlet property of the type

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to install a pre-made custom progress bar in my app and according to the tutorial from the website i got the code from, i need to:

`"On the view controller's header file create an IBOutlet property of the type MCPercentageDoughnutView and link it to the object you created on the Interface Builder."`

Can someone explain me how do I create an `IBOutlet` property of the type `MCPercentageDoughnutView`? I tried doing:

```
__weak IBOutlet MCPercentageDoughnutView *pieChart;
```

It gives me the error: `Unknown type name 'MCPercentageDoughnutView'`. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In header file you should also:

```
#import "MCPercentageDoughnutView.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the IBOutlet is to be declared in header file, you can do a forward declaration of MCPercentageDoughnutView in the header file and import the class MCPercentageDoughnutView.h file in your implementation file.

```
@class MCPercentageDoughnutView // In your header file

#import "MCPercentageDoughnutView.h" // In your implementation file
```

However, if the IBOutlet is to be declared in the implementation file (in your class' extension), the forward declaration in header file is not required.